# Convert Excel formulae (logic) to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for help on converting an Excel formula to SQL Server.

```
 =If(AND(N3="A", R3>O3), 
 R3,If(AND(N3="P",S3>O3),S3,If(N3="D","",If(OR(Q3="P",Q3="A")*AND(P3>TODAY(),P3>O3),P3,O3))))
```

SQL formula I tried ....Colum N & Q consists of varchar and other fields are datetime in SQL Server. In below SQL statement, I have replaced and (BOLD) with OR condition. When I use "AND"(bold) am getting right data in few cases if I use (OR), am getting right data in few other cases. Here is database structure with insert statements.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iHYxufV2NuyXwHeBM832NS/4

```
create table dbo.test (id int, N varchar(10), O datetime, P datetime, Q varchar(10), R datetime, S datetime)

select case when N='A' and R>O THEN R
when N='P' and S>O then S
when N='D' then ''
when (Q='P' or Q='Á') **and** p>getdate() and P>O then P else O end data
from test
```

output for above fiddler =
**id-data**

```
  1-2020-11-20 00:00:00
  2-2021-02-15 00:00:00
  3-2021-04-11 00:00:00
  4-2021-04-16 00:00:00
  5-2021-04-30 00:00:00
```

Comment: What is your table structure?  What are results for what have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried above SQL statement, in few cases am getting right data when I put 'And'' in last statement am getting data and  if i put ''OR'' in last statement, am getting right data. I'm bit confused with last when condition.
                                                                                                                               `create table dbo.test (id int, N varchar(10), O datetime, P datetime(), Q 
        varchar(10), R datetime, S getdate())`

Comment: I posted your create table to your question.  If you can post some data insert examples to match what you want to do it would be helpfl

Comment: how do I attach a document?

Comment: You don't attach a document. You paste it as text and use the code formatting button on the toolbar to set it apart.

Comment: I can do most of the conversion, but this part of the expression doesn't make sense, because there's a multiplication operation on the boolean expressions: `OR(Q3="P",Q3="A")*AND(P3>TODAY(),P3>O3)`

Comment: OK but that is how data and formula given to us to convert

Comment: I think this is creating either a 1 or 0 for the multiplication. You'll need to nest a case for that.

Comment: ok, am not able to think how to do. Could you please help me. I tried and failed.

Comment: All we really need is a sample of maybe four rows: two where `AND` produced the correct result, and two where `OR` produces the correct result, along with an additional column indicated what the expected result should be. **Do not post this as an image**.

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind: `when N='D' then ''` is **wrong**, because the other values are `DateTime`. You can't mix DateTime and string. You want `when N='D' then NULL` instead. Convert/coalesce to an empty string outside of this if you really need `''` instead of `NULL`. **This could also entirely explain why you get inconsistent results!** If you've set these up as strings, instead of dates, you might be getting wrong string comparisons instead of date comparisons, throwing off the calculation.

Comment: You can also use https://www.db-fiddle.com/ to set up some sample data and link us there.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iHYxufV2NuyXwHeBM832NS/1

Comment: Okay, that's two rows. Give us two more, **and include a column for the expected result of each row**. Also, you're using Sql Server, so we need sqlfiddle.com instead (this is my mistake).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228775/discussion-between-dinesh-kal-and-joel-coehoorn).

Comment: Joel, i have added data and expected output to original question

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `*` is a multiplication operator, but both sides of the expression are boolean rather than numeric. I *think* what's going on is Excel is converting the boolean true/false values to `1` and `0` for the multiplication operation.

**If this is correct, then `AND` is the correct operator and *almost* everything else in the translation is correct.**

There is one other mistake. `when N='D' then ''` is wrong, because the other result values all appear to be `DateTime` columns. *You can't mix strings and dates.* Instead, you need `when N='D' then NULL`.

```
 CASE WHEN N = 'A' AND R > O THEN R 
      WHEN N = 'P' AND S > O THEN S
      WHEN N = 'D' THEN NULL
      WHEN Q IN ('P', 'A') AND P > current_timestamp AND P > O THEN P
      ELSE O END
```

If you *really* need an empty string, you can convert the result and coalesce to empty string at a different level, but don't do it inside the `CASE` expression.

It's also worth noting the DateTime/String mismatch could entirely explain the strange results. If you have a sample somewhere for testing with the columns represented as Varchar values instead of Date or DateTime, then the comparisons could be wrong, throwing off the results. For example, `O` comes before `S` in the third row of sample data if they are compared as strings instead of dates.

Comment: @DineshKal You didn't include all the info I said we needed, and you should edit your question to include that link as part of the original text.

Comment: NOTE: for those who may not know: T-SQL does not have true booleans, and conditional expressions in SQL *do not* return booleans that can be converted to numbers.  Rather they return (implicit, internal) truth-state-conditions that can only be consumed by conditional clauses (IF, CASE) and other conditional expressions.  This is why client-side coding tricks that try to (implicitly, or explicitly) treat TRUE and FALSE as 1 and 0 do not work: TRUE and FALSE are not values in Sql, they are only internal evaluation states.

Answer (score 1):

If this is your verbatim code, you have an accented A in this line:

```
when (Q='P' or Q='Á') and p>getdate() and P>O then P else O end data
```

A and Á are not equivalent, so that may be short circuiting your OR and failing to return values for any Q = 'A' values that aren't handled further up in the logic.

Other than that your logic looks equivalent. The use of OR(...)*AND(...) is odd but does produce a 1/0 value, and your conversion into SQL has the correct boolean operators to match that logic.